# Component not remounting after passing axios request data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

When a user clicks on the Sales Overview tab, I want to make an axios request and then update various charts in that tab. I'm able to make the axios request, fetch the data and even get the data. However, on my 1st click on the Sales Overview tab, I don't see anything except the previous Dashboard component data(or whatever tab that I was previously on). But after clicking on another random tab and then clicking on the Sales Overview tab, I'm able to see the data that I want. Is this a mounting issue?

Here is the parent Search component code:

class Search extends Component {
state = {
hcp_id: 101,
sales_overview_data: [],
page_id_sales_overview: 4,
}

```
salesOverviewClicked = () => {
    // this.props.salesOverviewDataFromParent(this.state.sales_overview_data);
    console.log('Clicked on sales Overview!');
    let page_id = this.state.page_id_sales_overview;
    let hcp_id = this.state.hcp_id;
    console.log('state: ', this.state);
    axios.post('/test-json', {
        page_id: page_id,
        hcp_id: hcp_id
    })
        .then((res) => {
            const dataRequest = res.data;
            console.log('State before loading data in sales overview: ', this.state);
            console.log('received data inside sales overview', res.data);
            this.setState({ ...this.state, sales_overview_data: res.data });
            console.log('State after loading data in sales overview: ', this.state);
            // this.props.salesOverviewDataFromParent(this.state.sales_overview_data);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}


 return(
      <div>
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tablet-1"> <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link " data-toggle="tab" href="#tablet-2" > <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Engage with HCP</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link " data-toggle="tab" href="#tablet-3" onClick={this.salesOverviewClicked}> <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>Sales Overview</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link " data-toggle="tab" href="#tablet-4"> <i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i>Promotional Activity</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link " data-toggle="tab" href="#tablet-5"> <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>Patient Analysis</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
                            {this.state.receivedData.length !== 0 && <Dashboard data={this.state.receivedData} />}
                            <EngageWithHCP />
                            {this.state.sales_overview_data.length !== 0 && <SalesOverview1 key = {this.state.sales_overview_data} data={this.state.sales_overview_data} />}
                            <PromotionalActivity1 />
                            <PatientAnalysis1 />
                        </div>
```

And here is the SalesOverview1 child component:

```
 return(
 <div class='row'>
                        {
                            <ChartBox
                                data={this.props.data[401]}
                            />
                        }
   )
```

The chart inside SalesOverview1 comp is not being shown unless I click on some other tab first and then come back to the SalesOverview1 tab (even though data is being fetched on the first click on the Sales Overview tab).

Here is a basic visual of the tabs:

[image]

I think when I click on the tab, since the request takes time, the data isn't updated and I by default see the previous tab data. But once the data is fetched, I don't see the data on that tab because the tab component should be re-mounted which isn't happening apparently. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your child component add

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 // see if nextProps contains updated Data after data being fetched
 // if yes add state in child component and put data from nextprops and use state instead of this.props in render method
}
```

you can show loader in child component when data is empty, for this remove your check from parent component

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting! Can you please add a complete code as this is a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: I tried it but it's giving me an error. I used static getDerivedStateFromProps instead of the one you recommended.